# Wordpress post querying returns links

Tags: wordpress

I am modifying an out of the box wordpress theme. I am trying to do something rather simple, adding a post query to the homepage. Only the query is returning links wrapped around everything.

Here is my testing site:
http://calgarywildlife.org/wordpress/#

Any clues would be greatly appreciated
Thanks!

Here is my Code:

```
<?php query_posts( array('posts_per_page' => 2, 'cat=14') ); ?>
<ul>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
    <div class="hp-eventthumnb"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
    <div class"hp-eventdetails">    
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p><?php substr(the_excerpt(), 0 , 250); ?></p>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
    </div>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

UPDATE: 
It only appears to be happening on items generated from this query. I am add any other HTML to the page and it does not get treated the same way.

Comment: which button should i be clicking?

Comment: that is exactly the problem I am facing. It appears to return links on all of slider items(below the slider)

Answer (score 2):

One thing I see that might be causing issues is the following line:

```
<p><?php substr(the_excerpt(), 0 , 250); ?></p>
```

`the_excerpt()` is going to echo the excerpt value right away, instead of passing it to the `substr()` function.  You want `get_the_excerpt()`, which will **return** a string (instead of **echo**-ing).  The end result would look like this:

```
<p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0 , 250); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

how about setting some conditions like this, kind of messy but if you place this in i believe 
wp-content\themes\twentyten\header.php
it would capture the output of the variable, then you can direct it to the corresponding pages:

```
if($_GET['page_id']=='861')
//do something
if($_GET['page_id']=='865')
//do something
if($_GET['page_id']=='870')
etc....
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to find out what is generating these ahrefs so that I can fix the problem at the core.

Comment: you would end up re writing about 1/3 of WP.  there are lots of files in 'wp-includes' that reefers to permalinks

Comment: maybe we are not talking about the same thing. I am referring to:
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<p><?php substr(the_excerpt(), 0 , 250); ?></p>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>

Answer (score 0):

I found out what it was.
I embedded a link in the content of the slider took that came out of the box. For some reason it leaves the link open. I had to throw a `</a>` in there just below the slideshow. Hacky, but best I can come up with.